# Dynamic paragraphs with openTBS - strange behaviour

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

That's an array I have:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(4) { ["theme"]=> string(9) "тема2" ["description"]=> string(9) "опис2" ["literature_main"]=> string(7) "літ2" ["litarature_add"]=> string(7) "доп2" } 
[1]=> array(4) { ["theme"]=> string(9) "тема1" ["description"]=> string(9) "опис1" ["literature_main"]=> string(7) "літ1" ["litarature_add"]=> string(7) "доп1" } }
```

I'm trying to display it dynamically in .docx with the following template:

```
Theme: [item.theme;block=tbs:p]
Des: [item.description;block=tbs:p]
Lit1: [item.literature_main;block=tbs:p]
Lit2.: [item.litarature_add;block=tbs:p]
```

What I'm getting is just a mix of those two without des, lit1, lit2 even being displayed.

Basically, I get mess. And it seems like it's completely random process, cause if i remove all but theme[item.theme;block=tbs:p] then I get two paragraphs in word. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TinyButStrong, each section of block (defined with `block=tbs:p`) is considered as an [alternative section](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_section).

So, assuming each line in your snipped is a paragraph, your block definition should be :

```
Theme: [item.theme;block=4*tbs:p]
Des: [item.description]
Lit1: [item.literature_main]
Lit2.: [item.litarature_add]
```

Comment: Thx. Worked like a charm! Sorry for my stupidity, I've read all the documentation about opentbs and somehow missed this cool feature ("4*"). Thanks once more!